# Jupiter Swap raise Transfer: insufficient lamports

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, python, jupiter

I am trying to execute a swap on jupiter in Python.

I followed the doc https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-api
But when I execute I have an error:

> RPCException: SendTransactionPreflightFailureMessage { message:
> "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 3: custom
> program error: 0x1", data:
> RpcSimulateTransactionResult(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err:
> Some(InstructionError(3, Custom(1))), logs: Some(["Program
> ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program
> ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program
> ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program
> ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program
> ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]", "Program
> log: CreateIdempotent", "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log:
> Instruction: GetAccountDataSize", "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1569 of 1392795
> compute units", "Program return:
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=", "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success", "Program
> 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]", "Program
> 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program log: Initialize
> the associated token account", "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log:
> Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner", "Program log: Please upgrade
> to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support", "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 1386208
> compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
> success", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke
> [2]", "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3", "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3158 of 1382326
> compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
> success", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL
> consumed 20815 of 1399700 compute units", "Program
> ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success", "Program
> 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Transfer: insufficient
> lamports 382911515, need 400000000", "Program
> 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x1"]),
> accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(21115), return_data: None }) }

I see that I want to swap 0.4 SOL, and it seems that I am only sending 0.382911515. But how can I solve it as my input is already 0.4 SOL.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you identified, the error says the transaction wants to transfer 0.4 sol out of your account, but there's only ~0.38 there. Check your account balance and don't forget that you need a little bit more than 0.4 sol to swap that much since you might also need to pay for rent for the new token account of your output token and transaction+ priority fees.